# Number Game - Randomised

Tags: javascript

Need help to understand how to do the following:

1. Every 2 seconds interval, the two numbers will generate random numbers containing integers values from 1 to 3.
2. Upon pressing the "Match" button, if the two numbers are the same, the number on the green label increases by 1.
3. Upon pressing the "Match" button, if the two numbers are different, the number on the red label increases by 1.
4. If the two randomly generated numbers are the same, and user did not press the “Match” button in 2 seconds, the number on the purple label increases by 1.
5. Enhance the scoring system to ensure that the green label and red label will only increase by 1, even if the user presses more than once within the 2 seconds intervals.

Code:

```
 var no1, no2;

 function randomize(){
 no1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
 no2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
 }

 function print(){
 $("#number1 > span").text(no1);
 $("#number2 > span").text(no2);

 }

 function check(){
 if (no1 == no2){
 alert("Both numbers are the same")
 }
 if (no1 != no2){
 alert("Both numbers are the different")
 }
 }


 $().ready(function(){

 randomize()
 print()

 $(":input").click(function(){
 if (no1 == no2){
    alert("Both numbers are the same")
 }
 if (no1 != no2){
    alert("Both numbers are the different")
 }
 randomize()
 print()
 })

})
```

**Improvements to be made**

1. Every 2 seconds interval, the two numbers (i.e. Number 1 and Number 2) will generate random numbers containing integer values from 5 to 6.
2. For every random numbers generated, the 2 seconds interval will be reduced by 0.1 seconds.
3. The random speed text will show the current seconds interval for every random numbers generated.
4. Once the interval reaches 0.8 seconds, a javascript alert box will show the message “The interval has reached 0.8 seconds”.
5. When the user dismisses the alert, the random speed text is reset to the initial values and restarts the speed of two numbers to be randomly generated for every interval.

**Current Code**

```
var no1, no2, correctScore, wrongScore, missedScore, generatedNum, delay

function updateScreen(disabled) {
$('#correctScore').text(correctScore);
$('#wrongScore').text(wrongScore);
$('#missedScore').text(missedScore);
$('#generatedNum > span').text(generatedNum);
$("#number1 > span").text(no1);
$("#number2 > span").text(no2);
$(":input").val(generatedNum >= generateTotal ? "START!" : "MATCH!");
$(":input").prop('disabled', disabled);
}

function generate() {
if (no1 == no2 && !$(":input").prop('disabled')) ++missedScore;
if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) {
    updateScreen(false); // needed to show missedScore.
    if (confirm('The interval has reached 0.8 seconds')) start();
    return; // exit
}
no1 = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
no2 = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
++generatedNum;
updateScreen(false);
setTimeout(generate, delay *= 0.95);
}

function start() {
correctScore = wrongScore = missedScore = generatedNum = 0;
delay = 2000;
updateScreen(true);
generate();
}

function check() {
if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) return start(); // Start pressed
if (no1 == no2) {
    ++correctScore;
} else {
    ++wrongScore;
}
updateScreen(true); // disable button
}

$(function(){
$(":input").click(check);
start();
});

$(function(){
$(":input").click(check);
start();
});
```

Comment: Read about `setInterval` and/or `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint (:

Comment: @trincot tried, am I applying it correctly? https://jsfiddle.net/k58bbpf3/#&togetherjs=QRsbUQdPER

Comment: @user5992661 I am putting to together an example that should help.

Comment: @user5992661, as you put it in your question edit, there is an issue: the return value of *setInterval* is not anything related to *no1* or *no2*. In fact, the return value should not interest you. Just call *setInterval*. You have now two answer to look at. I tried to be concise in mine.

Comment: Thanks @trincot! Your example and comments are useful, appreciated (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working snippet, based on the code in your fiddle.

First some remarks:

- I modified the CSS a bit, using the `vw` unit of measure, so the size of the displayed elements adapts to the window size. Some other changes concern percentages instead of pixels, for the same reasons.
- An `input` tag [does not have an end-tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html#input.button-tags), so I removed that from the HTML.
- The script also updates the total number of generated pairs in the top row. For that I put the number in a separate `span`, since it is not very elegant to reproduce the text *"Random Numbers generated:"* every two seconds via script.
- To avoid that the user clicks twice for the same number pair, the `input` element will be disabled after the user clicks. It will be enabled again as soon as the next number pair is generated. This way the user has a visual indication of that restriction.
- To get random numbers in the range 1, 2, 3 you should *not* use:

  ```
  no1 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
  ```

  but:

  ```
  no1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  ```

  Because, if ever the random generated would produce a perfect 0, then you will have no1 == 0 in the first case.

After comments, the following features were added:

- A game consists of a pre-set number of generated pairs, after which the user must confirm whether to play again.
- The delay between two number generations is shortened with 5% each time.

Here is the code:

```js
var no1, no2, correctScore, wrongScore, missedScore, generatedNum, delay,
    generateTotal = 30;

function updateScreen(disabled) {
    $('#correctScore').text(correctScore);
    $('#wrongScore').text(wrongScore);
    $('#missedScore').text(missedScore);
    $('#generatedNum > span').text(generatedNum);
    $("#number1 > span").text(no1);
    $("#number2 > span").text(no2);
    $(":input").val(generatedNum >= generateTotal ? "START!" : "MATCH!");
    $(":input").prop('disabled', disabled);
}

function generate() {
    if (no1 == no2 && !$(":input").prop('disabled')) ++missedScore;
    if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) {
        updateScreen(false); // needed to show missedScore.
        if (confirm('Game over. Do you want to play again?')) start();
        return; // exit
    }
    no1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    no2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    ++generatedNum;
    updateScreen(false);
    setTimeout(generate, delay *= 0.95);
}

function start() {
    correctScore = wrongScore = missedScore = generatedNum = 0;
    delay = 2000;
    updateScreen(true);
    generate();
}

function check() {
    if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) return start(); // Start pressed
    if (no1 == no2) {
        ++correctScore;
    } else {
        ++wrongScore;
    }
    updateScreen(true); // disable button
}

$(function(){
    $(":input").click(check);
    start();
});
```

```css
body                     { text-align: center; background: antiquewhite; }
table                    { background: white; width: 100%; }
td                       { width: 16.67%; font-size: 3vw;  }
#correctScore            { background: lime;               }
#wrongScore              { background: coral;              }
#missedScore             { background: violet;             }
.numberStyle             { padding: 0.25em; color: blue;   }
.numberStyle span, input { font-size: 5vw;                 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="generatedNum" colspan="6">Random Numbers generated: <span>1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Number 1</td> <td colspan="3">Number 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" id="number1" class="numberStyle"><span>1</span></td>
        <td colspan="3" id="number2" class="numberStyle"><span>2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6"><input type="button" value="START!"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Correct</td><td id="correctScore"><span>0<span></td>
        <td>Wrong</td>  <td id="wrongScore">  <span>0<span></td>
        <td>Missed</td> <td id="missedScore"> <span>0<span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Run this snippet to see it work. See how it behaves in full screen as well.

Comment: Anyway to limit the random number generated to 30 and an alert box informs the user that game is over. Afterwards, user has to click on the alert box to try again?

Comment: Added a limit of 5, so you can quickly check. Just change the value on second JavaScript line to 30 or whatever limit you'd like.

Comment: Seemed complicated to write a script. Thanks pro! How can I display the text "Random Numbers generated:" at the first row?

Comment: The text "Random Numbers generated:" is displayed already in the first row. I see it when I run the snippet.

Comment: Resolved the issue. I notice there is a span placed before the text. Do you know how to reduce the 2 seconds interval by 0.1 seconds for every random numbers generated and changing the integer values from 5 to 6?

Comment: I added the variable delay, which will be reduced with 5% each time, which I think gives a better effect than reducing 0.1 seconds each time. I don't understand what you mean with *changing the integer values from 5 to 6*.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase... Every 2 seconds interval, the two numbers (i.e. Number 1 and Number 2) will generate random numbers containing integer values from 5 to 6. How do you do it?

Comment: So, either a 5 or a 6? That would give 4 possibilities: 5 - 5, 5 - 6, 6 - 5 and 6 - 6. Is that what you want? If that is what you want, then change `1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3)` to `5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2)`. So the first number in that formula is the lowest value you want to generate, and the last number is the count of possible numbers you want to get.

Comment: I would need that 4 possibilities to appear in the number game. However the change did not appear. Can you help to see if there is any mistake in my code? (Refer to the question for the Current Code.) I also need help with four other questions. I have stated them below the title: Improvements to be made.

Comment: I tried your version of the code, but it generates errors. You should *always* check the console for errors and fix them. You will not be able to program successfully it you do not have that habit. Debug, debug and debug. (In this case you did not define *generateTotal*).
Actually for a new question you should create a new question. It is not good practice to change questions and add new requirements to it. I would really suggest you remove the new requirements from this question, and put it in a new one. If you want you can post the link to that new question here, and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Still trying to debug those errors @tirncot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744031/number-game-increase-the-speed-of-two-numbers

Comment: Hi, that question is not well formulated, and will get closed soon. You should read that as if you saw it for the first time. Where is the HTML, CSS? Where is the question? You should specify what is your specific problem with the code as you have it. Please do that first if you want to prevent that question from being closed.

Answer (score 1):

I tweeked your Jsfiddle a little, Have a check and let me know if this helps. Here is the [Wroking Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/k58bbpf3/3/)

Adding the working snippet (Just consider my Jquery code logic)

```js
var no1, no2;

function randomize() {
  no1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
  no2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
}

function print() {
  $("#number1 > span").text(no1);
  $("#number2 > span").text(no2);

}

function check() {
  if (no1 == no2) {
    alert("Both numbers are the same")
  }
  if (no1 != no2) {
    alert("Both numbers are the different")
  }
}

$(function() {

  randomize();
  print();
  var clickedFlag = false;
  setInterval(function(){
    
    if(!clickedFlag)
    {
      var currNum = parseInt($('#missedScore span').text());
      $('#missedScore span').text(++currNum);  
    }
    
    clickedFlag = false;
    randomize();
    print();
    
    $(":input").off('click.RandomNum').on('click.RandomNum',function()  {
     clickedFlag = true;
     $(this).off('click.RandomNum');
      
     if(no1 == no2) {
      var currNum = parseInt($('#correctScore span').text());
      $('#correctScore span').text(++currNum);     
     }
     else if(no1 != no2) {
      var currNum = parseInt($('#wrongScore span').text());
      $('#wrongScore span').text(++currNum);     
     }  
      
  });
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

table {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

td {
  width: 150px;
}

span {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#correctScore {
  background-color: green;
}

#wrongScore {
  background-color: red;
}

#missedScore {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.numberStyle {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: blue;
}

.numberStyle span {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


  <table width="800" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td id="generatedNum" colspan="6" align="left"><span>Random Numbers generated : 1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">Number 1</td>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">Number 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" id="number1" class="numberStyle"><span>1</span></td>
      <td colspan="3" id="number2" class="numberStyle"><span>2</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50px" ;>
      <td colspan="6">
        <input type="button" value="MATCH!" style="font-size:50px;" />
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Correct:</td>
      <td id="correctScore"><span>0</span></td>
      <td><span>Wrong</span></td>
    <td id="wrongScore"><span>0</span></td>
    <td><span>Missed</span></td>
    <td id="missedScore"><span>0</span></td>
        
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! May I know what is Math.ceil used for?

Comment: I just modified your code to make it work. I tweeked only the part which will make it work. Rest all is your code. The math.ceil was already in there

Comment: Any way to limit the random number generated to 30 and an alert box informs the user that game is over. Afterwards, user has to click on the alert box to try again?

Comment: Yes you can keep a count right? it can be either total of all the counts (correct + wrong + missed)  else a new variable inside the interval which increments for every interval upto 30 counts

Answer (score 0):

My solution will allow you to make your game more extensible game if you choose to change your random number value ranges for example.

Live Preview(http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/qZBMOB)

HTML:

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
<div id="purple"></div>
<input id="match" type ="button" value="MATCH">
```

JQuery/JavaScript:

```
//interval time
var milliseconds = 2000;

//the random numbers to compare
var no1, no2;

//match button pressed counter
var matchPress = 0;

//scores for each box color
var red = 0,
green = 0,
purple = 0;

//create the interval
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {

  //store the random numbers between 1 and 3
  no1 = randomNumber(1, 3);

  no2 = randomNumber(1, 3);

  //boolean to check for match, true or false
  var match = no1 === no2;

  //debug
  console.log(match);

  //we have a match
  if (match && matchPress === 1) {

    //increment green
    green++;

    //increase the green score by 1
    $("#green").html(green);

  }
  //no match
  else if (!match && matchPress === 1) {

    //increment red
    red++;

    //increase the red score by 1
    $("#red").html(red);

  }
  //no button press but a match occured
  else if (matchPress !== 1 && match) {

    //increment purple
    purple++;

    //increase the purple score by 1
    $("#purple").html(purple);

  }

  //debug
  console.log("no1:" + no1 + " no2:" + no2);

  //enable the button
  $("#match").prop("disabled", false);

  //reset the matchPress counter
  matchPress = 0;

}, milliseconds);

function randomNumber(start, end) { //begin function

  //convert parameter to a number just in case its a string
  var thisStart = parseInt(start);

  //convert parameter to a number just in case its a string
  var thisEnd = parseInt(end);

  //return a random number between the start and end number
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (thisEnd - thisStart + 1) + thisStart);

}; //end function

//events
$("#match").on("click", function() {

  //set the matchPress flag to 1
  matchPress = 1;

  //disable the button
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);

});
```

CSS:

```
#red,
#green,
#purple {
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help and the helpful comments!

Comment: I am glad I could help.