# Number Game - Increase the speed of two numbers

Tags: javascript

**Question**

1. Every 2 seconds interval, the two numbers (i.e. Number 1 and Number 2) will generate random numbers containing integer values from 5 to 6.
2. For every random numbers generated, the 2 seconds interval will be reduced by 0.1 seconds.
3. The random speed text will show the current seconds interval for every random numbers generated.
4. Once the interval reaches 0.8 seconds, a javascript alert box will show the message “The interval has reached 0.8 seconds”.
5. When the user dismisses the alert, the random speed text is reset to the initial values and restarts the speed of two numbers to be randomly generated for every interval.

**Current Code**

```
var no1, no2, correctScore, wrongScore, missedScore, generatedNum, delay
generateTotal = 30;

function updateScreen(disabled) {
$('#correctScore').text(correctScore);
$('#wrongScore').text(wrongScore);
$('#missedScore').text(missedScore);
$('#generatedNum > span').text(generatedNum);
$("#number1 > span").text(no1);
$("#number2 > span").text(no2);
$(":input").val(generatedNum >= generateTotal ? "START!" : "MATCH!");
$(":input").prop('disabled', disabled);
}

function generate() {
if (no1 == no2 && !$(":input").prop('disabled')) ++missedScore;
if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) {
updateScreen(false); // needed to show missedScore.
if (confirm('The interval has reached 0.8 seconds')) start();
return; // exit
}
no1 = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
no2 = 5 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
++generatedNum;
updateScreen(false);
setTimeout(generate, delay *= 0.95);
}

function start() {
correctScore = wrongScore = missedScore = generatedNum = 0;
delay = 2000;
updateScreen(true);
generate();
}

function check() {
if (generatedNum >= generateTotal) return start(); // Start pressed
if (no1 == no2) {
++correctScore;
} else {
++wrongScore;
}
updateScreen(true); // disable button
}

$(function(){
$(":input").click(check);
start();
});

$(function(){
$(":input").click(check);
start();
});
```

Comment: Is this your school project ?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Yes for school project. The questions are those 5 pointers.

Comment: On the contrary; those listed 5 points are requirement for your application or script. You haven't really said what the problem with the code you've posted, if any.